# Android- How to recreate a CustomView in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, layout-inflater

I have a activity that implements a CustomView to inflate the ActionBar with a Checkbox. 
This Checkbox is a "LikeButton" to a article from a source and when the user swipe from left/right it load another articles from the same source.

The code is working fine for the first article that the user open, but when he swipe the Checkbox stays with the same state from the firt article.

How can I build a CustomView diferent for every article and inflate it when the user swipe?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) with [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) containing your custom views.  Also, for each fragment, make sure that you enable it's own options menu by calling `Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu(boolean hasMenu);`.  Once your do this, just Override your optionsMenu methods within your fragment classes.